# dnlib - how change application .NetFramework version

Tags: c#, dnlib

Can you tell me whether it is possible to change the `.NetFramework` version of another application using the dnlib library?

```
// Properties.Resources.MyExeFile - Binary file located in application resources
using var module = ModuleDefMD.Load(Properties.Resources.MyExeFile);
if (module.IsILOnly)
{
   module?.Write(Path.Combine(CurrDir, "Build.exe"));
}
```

Comment: It is possible, but you need to be more specific on from what version to what version.

Comment: @LexLi, 4.0 change to 4.5 version

Comment: You might build a hello world project for both .NET Framework 4.0 and 4.5, then compare the assemblies to learn the changes required. At least you need to modify `TargetFrameworkAttribute` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.versioning.targetframeworkattribute?view=netcore-3.1 but there might be other minor changes.

Comment: Why would you need to do this.